# PHP check-function for spanish DNI. Server Error 500, why?

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

I am desperate. Since days I am trying to implement a check-function in PHP for the spanish DNI. I am not finding my error. Can someone have a look on it?

```
<?php

require("bbdd.php");

$errors = '';
$dni = checkDNI($_POST['dni']);

/**
 * Function which checks if a string is a valid spanish DNI
 *
 * @param string $dniUnchecked
 * @return string $dni
 */      
function checkDNI($dniUnchecked) {
    //Possible values for the final letter
    $letterValues = array(
        'T' => 0, 'R' => 1, 'W' => 2, 'A' => 3, 'G' => 4, 'M' => 5,
        'Y' => 6, 'F' => 7, 'P' => 8, 'D' => 9, 'X' => 10, 'B' => 11,
        'N' => 12, 'J' => 13, 'Z' => 14, 'S' => 15, 'Q' => 16, 'V' => 17,
        'H' => 18, 'L' => 19, 'C' => 20, 'K' => 21, 'E' => 22
    );
    //Check if entered
    if($dniUnchecked == ''){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a DNI.<br/>';  
        echo $errors;
        return false;
    }       
    //Check length
    elseif(strlen($dniUnchecked) != 9){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a DNI that has 8 digits and a check-letter.<br/>';
        echo $errors;
        return false;
    }
    //Check validity
    elseif (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$/i', $dniUnchecked)) {
        //Check letter
        $checkArray = str_split($dniUnchecked);
        $checkArray[8] = $letterValues[$checkArray[8]];
        //var_dump($checkArray);
        $checkSum = 0;
        $i = 0;
        $factor = array(7, 3, 1, 7, 3, 1, 7, 3, 1);
        for($i=0; $i<9; $i++){
            $checkArray[$i] = (int)$checkArray[$i];
            $checkSum += ($checkArray[$i] *= $factor[$i]);
        }
        if((preg_match("/\d$/", $checkSum) == 3) {
        //All was ok
        echo 'all ok';
            $dni = trim($dniUnchecked);
            $dni = stripsplashes($dni);
            $dni = htmlspecialchars($dni);
            return $dni;
        } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid DNI.<br/>';
        echo $errors;
        }
    }
}
```

When I checkout old commits, then at least the checks if and the first elseif are working. When I implement the second elseif, nothing happens anymore. As you can see I want to see the errors from PHP but there is nothing. Just a 500.
Would be cool if someone shows me a mistake or shows me the direction. Thanks!

---

### Working Version IMHO

```
$dni = checkDNI($_POST['dni']);

/**
 * Function which checks if a string is a valid spanish DNI
 *
 * @param string $dniUnchecked
 * @return string $dni
 */      
function checkDNI($dniUnchecked) {
    //Error-Output
    $errors = '';
    //Possible values for the final letter
    $letterValues = array(
        'T' => 0, 'R' => 1, 'W' => 2, 'A' => 3, 'G' => 4, 'M' => 5,
        'Y' => 6, 'F' => 7, 'P' => 8, 'D' => 9, 'X' => 10, 'B' => 11,
        'N' => 12, 'J' => 13, 'Z' => 14, 'S' => 15, 'Q' => 16, 'V' => 17,
        'H' => 18, 'L' => 19, 'C' => 20, 'K' => 21, 'E' => 22
    );
    //Check if entered
    if($dniUnchecked == ''){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a DNI.<br/>';  
        echo $errors;
        return false;
    }       
    //Check length
    elseif(strlen($dniUnchecked) != 9){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a DNI that has 8 digits and a check-letter.<br/>';
        echo $errors;
        return false;
    }
    //Check validity
    elseif (preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$/i', $dniUnchecked)) {
        // take numbers as big integer
        $checkNumber = (int)substr($dniUnchecked, 0, 8);
        var_dump($checkNumber);
        // modulo 23 and check if modulo equals corresponding checkletter
        if($checkNumber % 23 == $letterValues[substr($dniUnchecked, 8, 1)]){
        //All was ok
        echo 'all ok';
            $dni = trim($dniUnchecked);
            $dni = stripslashes($dni);
            $dni = htmlspecialchars($dni);
            return $dni;
        } else {
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid DNI.<br/>';
        echo $errors;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have PHP error reporting turned on? If not, why not? If so, have you checked your error logs? Have you checked web server error logs?  Have you made any debugging efforts?  Where does the script behavior vary from what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `(`:

```
if((preg_match("/\d$/", $checkSum) == 3) {
// ^
// there
```

But seriously, turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)!

You can do that in a couple of ways. For example:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of your script.

Comment: Yeah thanks! Error reporting was definitely on. I erased the extra (. But it seems to be a problem with my VirtualBox. I've got no idea what the problem is. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. I cannot test it at the moment...but it will be hopefully working when time goes by.